# JavaScript Alert si se ejecutó el insert(query) PHP, MySQL y JS

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, sql, alert

```html
<?php
require_once "conexion.php";

$objConexion = Conectarse();

if (isset($_GET['mensaje1'])) {
    echo '<script> swal("¡Alerta!", "'.$_GET['mensaje0'].'", "warning")</script>';
}

?>


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es"> 
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="img/Favicon.png">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/estilos.css">
    
    <title>OF Gestión de Empleados</title>
</head>

<body id="CommonBody">
    <header id="CommonH">
        <img style="filter: brightness(1.0); mix-blend-mode: multiply;" src="img/RSocial.png">
        <h2>OF1.0</h2>
            <div class="activeuser">
                <div id="circle"></div>
                <!-- <?php echo ucwords($_SESSION['user']['UsuNombredeUsuario']);?> -->
                <a class="nl" href=""> Cerrar Sessión </a>
            </div>
        
    </header>

    <aside id="CommonA">

        <button class="Btn" type="submit" style="background: #092150; cursor: auto;">Gestión Empleados</button>

        <a href="gestionusuarios.php">
        <button class="Btn" type="submit">Gestión Usuarios</button>
        </a>

        <a href="gestionclientes.php">
        <button class="Btn" type="submit">Gestión Clientes</button>
        </a>

    </aside>

    <section id="CommonS">
        <h1>Gestionar Empleados</h1>
        <form action="validaringresaremp.php" method="POST" id="GestionEmp">
            <div class="ItemsForm">
                <label class="Lbl" for="TipoDoc">Tipo Documento de Identidad</label>
                <select class="Inp" id="TipoDoc" name="TipoDoc" required>
                    <option disabled="" selected="selected">Seleccionar</option>
                    <option value="TarjetadeIdentidad">Tarjeta de Identidad</option>
                    <option value="CeduladeCiudadania">Cédula de Ciudadanía</option>
                    <option value="PEP">PEP</option>
                    <option value="CedulaExtrangeria">Cédula de Extrangería</option>
                    <option value="PET">PET</option>
                </select>
            </div>

            <div class="ItemsForm">
                <label class="Lbl" for="NumDoc">No. Documento</label>
                <input class="Inp" id="NumDoc" type="number" name="NumeroDocIdentidad" placeholder="# Identidad" required>
            </div>

            <div class="ItemsForm">
                <label class="Lbl" for="1erNombre">Primer Nombre</label>
                <input class="Inp" id="1erNombre" type="text" name="PrimerNombre" placeholder="Ingresar 1er Nombre" required>
            </div>

            <div class="ItemsForm">
                <label class="Lbl" for="2doNombre">Segundo Nombre</label>
                <input class="Inp" id="2doNombre" type="text" name="SegundoNombre" placeholder="Ingresar 2do Nombre">
            </div>

            <div class="ItemsForm">
                <label class="Lbl" for="1erApellido">Primer Apellido</label>
                <input class="Inp" id="1erApellido" type="text" name="PrimerApellido" placeholder="Ingresar 1er Apellido" required>
            </div>

            <div class="ItemsForm">
                <label class="Lbl" for="2doApellido">Segundo Apellido</label>
                <input class="Inp" id="2doApellido" type="text" name="SegundoApellido" placeholder="Ingresar 2do Apellido">
            </div>

            <div class="ItemsForm">
                <label class="Lbl" for="FechaNacimiento">Fecha de Nacimiento</label>
                <input class="Inp" id="FechaNacimiento" type="date" name="FechaNacimiento" required>
            </div>

            <div class="ItemsForm">
                <label class="Lbl" for="Correo">Correo</label>
                <input class="Inp" id="Correo" type="email" name="Correo" placeholder="Ingresar Correo" required>
            </div>

            <div class="ItemsForm">
                <label class="Lbl" for="TelFijo">Teléfono Fijo</label>
                <input class="Inp" id="TelFijo" type="tel" name="TelefonoFijo" placeholder="(062) 274 5028">
            </div>

            <div class="ItemsForm">
                <label class="Lbl" for="TelCelular">Teléfono Celular</label>
                <input class="Inp" id="TelCelular" type="tel" name="TelefonoCelular" placeholder="(314) 881 2060" required>
            </div>

            <div class="ItemsForm">
                <label class="Lbl" for="Dir">Dirección</label>
                <input class="Inp" id="Dir" type="text" name="Direccion" placeholder="Ingresar Dirección" required>
            </div>

            <div class="ItemsForm">
                <label class="Lbl" for="Barrio">Barrio</label>
                <input class="Inp" id="Barrio" type="text" name="Barrio" placeholder="Ingresar Barrio" required>
            </div>

            <div class="ItemsForm">
                <label class="Lbl" for="Ciudad">Ciudad</label>
                <input class="Inp" id="Ciudad" type="text" name="Ciudad" placeholder="Ingresar Ciudad" required>
            </div>

            <div class="ItemsForm">
                <label class="Lbl" for="Cargo">Cargo</label>
                <select class="Inp" id="Cargo" name="Cargo" required>
                    <option disabled="" selected="selected">Seleccionar</option>
                    <option value="Gerente(a)">Gerente(a)</option>
                    <option value="Contador(a)">Contador(a)</option>
                    <option value="AuxiliarAdministrativo(a)">Auxiliar Administrativo(a)</option>
                    <option value="Asesor(a)deVentas">Asesor(a) de Ventas</option>
                </select>
            </div>

            <div class="ItemsForm">
                <label class="Lbl" for="FechaIngreso">Fecha de Ingreso</label>
                <input class="Inp" id="FechaIngreso" type="date" name="FechaIngreso" required>
            </div>

            <div class="ItemsForm">
                <label class="Lbl" for="FechaRetiro">Fecha de Retiro</label>
                <input class="Inp" id="FechaRetiro" type="date" name="FechaRetiro">
            </div>
        </form>
    </section>

        <!-- Botones fuera del formulario (No hacen nada "Supongo que se deben configurar con Js") -->
        <section id="CommonSBtn">
            <button id="IngresarEmp" class="Btn">Ingresar</button>
        </section>

</body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/actionjs.js"></script>
</html>
```

```php
<?php
require_once "conexion.php";
extract ($_REQUEST);

$objConexion = Conectarse();

// función para mostrar alerta si se efectua el insert
function empNoExiste(){
    $mensaje0 = "El Empleado se ha Registrado con Éxito";
    header("Location: gestionusuarios.php?mensaje=$mensaje0");
}

// función para mostrar alerta en caso que el registro ya exista
function empExiste(){
    $mensaje1 = "Ya Existe Empleado";
    header("Location: gestionusuarios.php?mensaje=$mensaje1");
}

// Capturar variable del form gestionempleados
$NumDoc = isset($_POST['NumeroDocIdentidad']) ? $_POST['NumeroDocIdentidad'] : '';

// query para comparar la variable con la base y realizar insert
$sql = mysqli_query($objConexion, "SELECT COUNT(*) AS total FROM tblempleados WHERE EmpIdentificacion='$NumDoc'");
$row = mysqli_fetch_object($sql);
if($row->total == 0){
    $query = mysqli_query($objConexion, "insert into tblempleados (EmpIdentificacion, EmpTipodeIdentificacion, Emp1erNombre, Emp2doNombre, Emp1erApellido, Emp2doApellido, EmpFechaNacimiento, EmpTelefonoFijo, EmpCelular, EmpCorreo, EmpDireccion, EmpBarrio, EmpCiudad, EmpCargo, EmpFechaIngreso, EmpFechaRetiro) values ('$_REQUEST[NumeroDocIdentidad]','$_REQUEST[TipoDoc]','$_REQUEST[PrimerNombre]','$_REQUEST[SegundoNombre]','$_REQUEST[PrimerApellido]','$_REQUEST[SegundoApellido]','$_REQUEST[FechaNacimiento]','$_REQUEST[TelefonoFijo]','$_REQUEST[TelefonoCelular]','$_REQUEST[Correo]','$_REQUEST[Direccion]','$_REQUEST[Barrio]','$_REQUEST[Ciudad]','$_REQUEST[Cargo]','$_REQUEST[FechaIngreso]','$_REQUEST[FechaRetiro]')");

    empNoExiste();

}
else {

    empExiste();

}
```

Espero se encuentren bien.

La situación es que tengo un formulario (gestionempleados.php) en PHP que me carga unos registros de empleados y los envía a una base MySQL a través de un documento (validaringresaremp.php) el insert se está realizando de manera correcta. Lo que necesito es crear un alert de JS que me permita mostrar un mensaje Éxito o Fracaso usando JS. Es decir si se hace el insert muestre un alert y si no muestre otro pero con JS; ya que quiero que salga la ventanita emergente **y lo más importante que no se vea el pantallaso blanco** que ocurre cuando se envían los datos capturados del form al documento de validaringresaremp.php. Espero haberme explicado lo suficiente y me puedan ayudar. Muchas gracias por su atención y que tengan un Excelente día.

Comment: Busca información y ejemplos de ajax y swal (sweetalert2), pues supongo que es lo que necesitas. Por otra parte, debes mejorar la pregunta para que sea válida en este sitio. Léete [ask], [tour] y [example] para aprender el funcionamiento del sitio y para obtener mejores respuestas.

Comment: Hola, buenas tardes. Muchas gracias por tu respuesta. Estaré al pendiente de tus recomendaciones ya que es la primera vez que formulo pregunta; de hecho hoy a penas hice el registro. Buscaré información sobre lo que me recomienda. Espero que haya una forma solo con js; ya que apenas estoy iniciando en este mundo. Gracias y Feliz tarde

Comment: Hay varias maneras, si puedes adjuntar tu código para poder ayudarte mejor, recuerda siempre al realizar preguntas adjuntar el código en forma de texto, con esto evitas que cierren tu pregunta y obtener buenas respuestas, muestra el intento que has realizado.

Comment: Muchas gracias Antonio, he agregado el código del documento de carga  validaringresaremp.php ahí se observa  la conexión, los alert (Js) y el query. ¡Muchas Gracias!

Comment: Bien, ahora cual es el problema, por lo observo en tus **if** ejecutas una **funcion** según la condición, dichas funciones muestran el mensaje en el **echo "alert()"**, no funcionan?, te manda error?, que sucede?...

Comment: Ahora tendrias que poner el formulario en la pregunta, pues si lo que pretendes es que no se vea el pantallazo en blanco deberias usar javascript para capturar el submit del formulario, detener su ejecución por defecto, y enviar los datos por ajax y manejar su respuesta y/o redirección.

Comment: Acabo de agregar el formulario. Algo para tener en cuenta es que el botón que envía el formulario está fuera de éste y estoy ejecutando el submit desde js ----- var myformEmp = document.getElementById("GestionEmp");
document.getElementById("IngresarEmp").addEventListener("click", function ingresarEmp() {
myformEmp.submit();
});

Comment: Antonio el insert funciona bien y los alert saltan correctamente pero saltan en una pantalla en blanco que es la de validaringresaremp.php y luego regresa al formulario. No sé si me explico. Yo deseo que no se vea que el sale del form, se va al documento del query salta el alert mostrando pantalla blanca y vuelve al form; sino que el alert salte en el form sin que se vea el pantallaso blanco del documento del query. ¿No sé si me explico?

Comment: Te explicas, pero no pongas el código de javascript en los comentarios porque es fundamental para ayudarte con la respuesta, y no aparece aún en la pregunta. Tampoco pongas código PHP dentro de un snippet porque no funciona, sino que usa bloques de código para ello.  La solución a tu problema sigue siendo el uso de lo que ya he mencionado en mis anteriores comentarios, el uso de ajax para que la página permanezca inmutable hasta que se haya procesado la inserción o no. Es un cambio un poco brusco de mentalidad, pero es que no tienes otra forma si quieres usar alert o swal sin pagina en blanco

Comment: Vale, ofrezco disculpas por no saber cómo manejar la plataforma. Haré lo posible por mejorar, solo quiero aprender y tratar de solucionar una situación en la que llevo ya varios días. Entonces entiendo según lo que dices que con puro html, js y php no se puede. Perfecto. Ya que no me quiero saturar de otros lenguajes o librerías por ahora. Feliz noche

Comment: Ajax es javascript, no es ningun lenguage en si, es una forma de usarlo con funciones específicas para ello.  Hay librerias como jquery que facilitan mucho su uso en lugar de usar objetos puros de javascript, aunque tambien tienes [fetch()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) si renuncias a usar librerias de javascript externas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En vista de que ya planteaste mejor el problema y las alertas ahora son las que no funcionan, he editado la respuesta.
Seguimos usando `SWEET ALERT`, he utilizado también `jQuery` y `Bootstrap`

Intenta de esta forma, debería funcionarte bien :)

**ARCHIVO gestionempleados.php**

```
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@11"></script>

<?php
    require_once "conexion.php";
    $objConexion = Conectarse();

    if (isset($_GET['mensajex'])) {
        echo '<script> 
                $( document ).ready(function() { 
                    Swal.fire({
                        icon: "info",
                        title: "Alerta",
                        text: "'.$_GET['mensajex'].'"
                    }) 
                });
            </script>';
    }else{
        echo '<script> 
                $( document ).ready(function() { 
                    Swal.fire({
                        icon: "info",
                        title: "Alerta",
                        text: "PRUEBA DE QUE SI SE ESTÁN EJECUTANDO LAS ALERTAS :V"
                    }) 
                });
            </script>';
    }
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es"> 
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="img/Favicon.png">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/estilos.css">

    <title>OF Gestión de Empleados</title>
</head>
```

**ARCHIVO validaringresaremp.php**

```
<?php
require_once "conexion.php";
extract ($_REQUEST);

$objConexion = Conectarse();

// función para mostrar alerta si se efectua el insert
function empNoExiste(){
    $mensajex = "El Empleado se ha Registrado con Éxito";
    header("Location: gestionusuarios.php?mensajex=$mensajex");
}

// función para mostrar alerta en caso que el registro ya exista
function empExiste(){
    $mensajex = "Ya Existe Empleado";
    header("Location: gestionusuarios.php?mensajex=$mensajex");
}

// Capturar variable del form gestionempleados
$NumDoc = isset($_POST['NumeroDocIdentidad']) ? $_POST['NumeroDocIdentidad'] : '';

// query para comparar la variable con la base y realizar insert
$sql = mysqli_query($objConexion, "SELECT COUNT(*) AS total FROM tblempleados WHERE EmpIdentificacion='$NumDoc'");
$row = mysqli_fetch_object($sql);
if($row->total == 0){
    $query = mysqli_query($objConexion, "insert into tblempleados (EmpIdentificacion, EmpTipodeIdentificacion, Emp1erNombre, Emp2doNombre, Emp1erApellido, Emp2doApellido, EmpFechaNacimiento, EmpTelefonoFijo, EmpCelular, EmpCorreo, EmpDireccion, EmpBarrio, EmpCiudad, EmpCargo, EmpFechaIngreso, EmpFechaRetiro) values ('$_REQUEST[NumeroDocIdentidad]','$_REQUEST[TipoDoc]','$_REQUEST[PrimerNombre]','$_REQUEST[SegundoNombre]','$_REQUEST[PrimerApellido]','$_REQUEST[SegundoApellido]','$_REQUEST[FechaNacimiento]','$_REQUEST[TelefonoFijo]','$_REQUEST[TelefonoCelular]','$_REQUEST[Correo]','$_REQUEST[Direccion]','$_REQUEST[Barrio]','$_REQUEST[Ciudad]','$_REQUEST[Cargo]','$_REQUEST[FechaIngreso]','$_REQUEST[FechaRetiro]')");

    empNoExiste();

}
else {

    empExiste();

}
```

Comment: Hola EvilFearzZ. Muchas gracias por tu colaboración y aporte. Está genial pero creo que yo lo tengo mal planteado. Como digo; a penas estoy aprendiendo y pues se me dificulta tener un código muy limpio. Ahora bien hice los cambios y me inserta o no y redirige normal; pero no saltan los alert. No sé qué estaré haciendo mal. Cambio el Código php y adjunto el form. ¡Muchas gracias por su comprensión y ayuda!

Comment: He editado la respuesta, prueba si te sirve. Saludos!